# Align text underneath image within table structure

Tags: css, image, html-table

I am trying to make a media library template in HTML & CSS, where I can add images to a table. I wish to add a caption directly underneath the images.

But my output is currently wrong. I get:

[image]

The text is aligned wrong, I cannot find a way to get the text directly under and centered underneath the image.

Here is my code template:

```
<div align="center" class="tile_div">
<table class="tile_table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/> 
        <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
    </td>
</tr>
    <td>
        <img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/> 
        <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
    </td>
</tr>
    <td>
        <img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/> 
        <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
    </td>
</tr>
    <td>
        <img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/> 
        <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
    </td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

My CSS is:

```
.tile_div{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.tile_table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.tile_table tr, td{
}

.tile_image{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.tile_p{
    display: inline;
}
```

Can anyone help with a solution to this problem?

Comment: remove the `.tile_p{ display: inline; }` completely and you're good

Comment: +1 for that seeming like the right solution, -1 for not making it an Answer

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with PHP, it's better just to show your HTML.

Comment: when I remove .tile_p it gives me [this](http://i.imgur.com/CDvOT.png)

Comment: it should not behave like that.. probably it does because you have a syntax error in your HTML - a missing `>` in `echo '<div align="center" class="tile_div"';`

Comment: You should post the _rendered_ html and/or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Seems fine as-is http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/U79jK/.

Comment: @j08691 not really if you look at wider screen :)

Comment: @ZoltanToth - excellent point. damn you, tightwad employer and your tiny monitors!

Comment: Wouldn't inserting `<br />` tags between the image and paragraph solve this?

Comment: The solution was that missed '>', which i'm embarrassed about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to clear up, the problem was closing the div tag metioned by @ZoltanToth in the main comments.

Here is the code that works and creates my desired output:

**HTML:**

```
        <div align="center" class="tile_div">
            <table class="tile_table">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img class="tile_image" height="100px" width="100px" src="default.jpg"/> 
                        <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img class="tile_image" height="100px" width="100px" src="default.jpg"/> 
                        <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img class="tile_image" height="100px" width="100px" src="default.jpg"/> 
                        <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**CSS** :

```
.tile_div{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.tile_table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.tile_table tr, td{
  text-align: center;
}

.tile_image{
    padding: 3px 5px 0px 3px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.tile_p{
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Thanks for your input. Thanks C.

Answer (score 3):

All credit to Zoltan Toth for providing the answer, remove the

```
.tile_p{
    display: inline;
}
```

I converted your code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jC3BR/)

Answer (score 2):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/bGtsX/).

## html

```
<table class='tile_table'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/>
      <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/>
      <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/>
      <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/>
      <p class="tile_p">Sound</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## css

```
.tile_table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.tile_table td {
  text-align: center;
}

.tile_image{
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<div align="center" class="tile_div">';
echo '<table class="tile_table">';
echo "<tr>";
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
echo "<td><table><tr><td>";
echo '<img class="tile_image" height="60px" width="60px" src="default.jpg"/></td></tr>'; 
echo '<tr><td><p class="tile_p">Sound</p></td></tr></table>';
echo "</td>";
 }
echo "</tr>";
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Table inside a table.